# getting "Duplicate class" error after adding Meta Audience Network - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook, dependencies, ads

whenever I try to build my app after adding meta dependency I get this error message:
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-25.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Answer (score 12):

You can add below 2 lines into your gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```